# Which is correct a or the?

Tags: articles, sentence-choice

> I want to thank you for a wonderful first semester.

OR

> I want to thank you for the wonderful first semester.

Answer (score 1):

These mean different things:

*I want to thank you for a wonderful first semester.* - *a WFS* is not especially stressed, just one semester and, perhaps, it's not over yet.

*I want to thank you for the wonderful first semester*, on the other hand, means that *the WFS* almost certainly lies in the past and it is *that* semester, both the speaker and listeners know what is being talked about.

So, I think the common knowledge is not crucial in this case, a time frame matters.

Answer (score 0):

Does the person or audience you are talking to know what you would mean by "wonderful first semester"?  If so, then you'd use *the*.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank you for a wonderful first semester.

We use the indefinite article to give a description of the impression that we have received personally while studying in the first semester. We consider the first semester as wonderful.

I want to thank you for the wonderful first semester.

In this case, we inform our interlocutor that it is a common knowledge that that the first semester was (has been) wonderful. That is why we use the definite article for marking the fact that is well known to everyone.